# How can I deploy my Java Web Project multiple times to the same or different servers?

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, glassfish

I'm trying to simulate a situation where there are multiple `Store` Web services. Each `Store` is a Java Web Application project containing a web service that provides operations `getPrice(item)` and `buy(item)`, and an XML file which serves as a database to track inventory.

If a `Store` is out of an item when a customer requests it, it can `buy` it from another `Store` and return it to customer. So `Store`s both provide a `Store` service and consume a `Store` service.

I've only created one project `Store` in Netbeans. I want to deploy 10 of them to test it out.

The only way I can think of doing this now is manually copying and pasting the project 10 times and changing the URLs in each one and then deploying them one by one. However, I can't help but think **there must be a better way**. I wish I could help but think of the way, but I can't.

Anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: You can set-up a batch script for this. Ant, Maven & Jenkins are your friends.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something called a Continuous Integration server to accomplish this.

A free, popular and dependable CI is [JenkinsCI](https://jenkins-ci.org/)

If you use Jenkins, you must set up remote scripts on the shop for Jenkins to execute to properly conduct a remote deployment.

Comment: Thank you for the general concept, but do you have any more specific advice? Reading through the whole Jenkins with my level of inexperience will take time and be inefficient